# Split a field from a document into multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have logs captured in elastic index, the variable "message" in an index holds entire log message. I wanted to split that data into multiple fields like timstamp, ip etc.
Note: The logs are pumped directly into elastic from our application using POST.

I have created grok to split this information, but i am not sure how to transform this on the fly.

```
  {
    "_index" : "logs_exception",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "9RI-BGoBwdzZ5ffB3_Sj",
    "_score" : 2.4795628,
    "_source" : {
      "CorrelationId" : "bd3fc7d6-ca39-44e1-9a59-xxasdasd1",
      "Message" : "2019-04-10 10:36:27,780 [8] ERROR LoggingService.TestConsole.Program [(null)] - System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain."
    }
```

can we create a pipeline in elastic to feed from one of the index and apply grok and push it back to another index? or whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Log to a file. Use filebeat to read the file and output to logstash. Use grok filter in logstash to transform the log message and configure logstash output to elasticsearch.

Comment: hmmm, any other alternative?
we already have the logs coming into elasticsearch in real time, cant we transform from elastic somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is to configure  the [Ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) to pre process your documents before indexing it in to es.

In your case you need a [Grok Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/grok-processor.html) to match the message field and separate it in to fields, Below is a sample pipeline definition with [Grok Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/grok-processor.html) to ingest your document in to elastic

```
{
      "description" : "...",
      "processors": [
        {
          "grok": {
            "field": "message",
            "patterns": ["%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}\[(?<misc1>.*)\]%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:originator}%{SPACE}\[(?<misc2>.*)\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:data}"]
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

With the above pipeline definition in place your data will be indexed as below.

```
{
    "_index" : "logs_exception",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "9RI-BGoBwdzZ5ffB3_Sj",
    "_score" : 2.4795628,
    "_source" : {
      "CorrelationId" : "bd3fc7d6-ca39-44e1-9a59-xxasdasd1",
      "timestamp" : "19-04-10 10:36:27,780",
      "misc1" : 8,
      "loglevel": ERROR,
      "originator": "LoggingService.TestConsole.Program",
      "misc2": (null),
      "data" : "- System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.",
      "Message" : "2019-04-10 10:36:27,780 [8] ERROR LoggingService.TestConsole.Program [(null)] - System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain."
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of json filter:

```
filter {
    json => {
        source=>message
        target=>event
    }
}
```